# Krull Dimension of $\mathbb{C}[[X,Y]]/(Y^2)$

Tags: solution-verification, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series, krull-dimension

I want to compute the Krull Dimension of the ring $\mathbb{C}[[X,Y]]/(Y^2)$. I have tried the following and would be glad if somebody could verify or point out mistakes in the following proof:

Let $y=Y$ mod $(Y^2)$ and $f:\mathbb{C}[[X,Y]]\to \mathbb{C}[[X]][y]$ be the map sending $X\mapsto X,Y\mapsto y$. Then $\mathbb{C}[[X,Y]]/(Y^2)\cong\mathbb{C}[[X]][y]$. So the dimension of these rings are the same. But $\mathbb{C}[[X]]\subset\mathbb{C}[[X]][y]$ is an integral extension because the polynomial $T^2\in\mathbb{C}[[X]][T]$ annihilates $y$. Now we see that
\begin{align*}
\dim\mathbb{C}[[X]]=\dim\mathbb{C}[[X]][y]=\dim\mathbb{C}[[X,Y]]/(Y^2)
\end{align*}
But $\dim\mathbb{C}[[X]]=1$ because $\dim\mathbb{C}[[X]]$ is a PID (which is not a field). Thus, $\dim\mathbb{C}[[X,Y]]/(Y^2)=1$.

I think one could also use the theorem that states "$\dim A/(a)=\dim A-1$" for $(A,m)$ a local Noetherian ring and $a\in m$ a non-zero divisor, but I explicitly tried to prove it without this result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think your proof is good, modulo a few words mentioned, e.g. $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$ is a principal ideal *domain* which is not a field. I also agree that the general result about modding out by a non-zerodivisor is probably best.

Comment: One other useful tool is that the Krull dimension of $R$ is the same as the Krull dimension of $R/\mathfrak{N}(R) = R_{\mathrm{red}}$. Quotienting out nilpotent elements does not change the poset of prime ideals, since all prime ideals contain all nilpotents.

Comment: Ah I see, so if we set $R=\mathbb{C}[[X,Y]]/(Y^2)$ and quotient out $Y$ we get $\text{dim}R=\text{dim}R/(Y)=\text{dim}\mathbb{C}[[X]]=1$, is that right?